# C# extended class doesn't expose methods on different project

Tags: c#, inheritance, class-visibility

I'm scratching my head on a problem that seems easy...I've published a NuGet package on my private server. This contains the SqlDb class:

```
public class SqlDb
{
    public void SetConnectionString(string connectionString)
    {
        // CODE
    }
}
```

The goal is to use this package in another solution with two projects: App.Database and App.Server. On App.Database I would like to manage all methods to MySQL and access them from App.Server.

***App.Database*** contains:

```
public class Db : SqlDb
{
}
```

***App.Server*** contains:

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var db = new Db();
        db.SetConnectionString(args[0]);
    }
}
```

App.Server has a reference to App.Database (I can access Db() class) but I can't see inherited methods from SqlDb (like SetConnectionString()).

Someone can help me to understand what I'm doing wrong ? Should I rewrite each method like:

```
public class Db : SqlDb
{
    public void SetConnectionString(string connectionString)
    {
        base.SetConnectionString(connectionString);
    }
}
```

I hope not...

Comment: Hmm this sounds like a problem with how c# shares code between projects, even if in the same solution.

Have you tried creating the DB class (and other classes you want to share ) as a library project or package it as an assembly in order to reference across the solution?

Comment: Yes, I've already done without success. App.Database is a library project (with reference to the NuGet package). When solution compiles (commenting the line with `db.SetConnectionString(args[0]);`) I can see that the compiler order is correct (first compiles App.Database, then uses the new .dll as reference for App.Server).

Comment: Do you see any error when you try to call your method `db.SetConnectionString`? It should work.  Something like this *`Db` does not contain a definition for 'SetConnectionString' and no accessible extension method 'SetConnectionString' accepting a first argument of type 'Db' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*. As another suggestion, try to remove `internal ` keyword.